# Page is not redirecting

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm having a problem with ASP.net redirection.

The `Copy()` method below is called from a javascript button in a grid with ajax and it works fine. It redirects to the `Create` action of the controller.

```
<AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)> _
Sub Copy(ByVal noDemande As Integer)
    Response.Redirect("/DemandeDeMontage/Create/" & noDemande)
End Sub
```

The `Create` action is a page that lets me edit the fields before saving them to the database.  When an `Id` is passed, the fields will be pre-filled with another record's info (copied info).

```
<AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)> _
Function Create(Optional ByVal id As Integer? = Nothing) As ActionResult
    If (id Is Nothing) Then
        Dim dmd As New DEMND_MONTG
        Return View("Edit", dmd)
    Else
        Dim dmd As ODCT0124_DEMND_MONTG = _dmdMontRep.getDmdById(id)
        dmd.CO_STAT = ModuleCommon.Status.AwaitingSave
        Return View("Edit", dmd)
    End If
End Function
```

There are no errors in the code above.

When debugging, everything seems to work. The `Copy` action is called, then `Create`, and then I can step through the HTML code of the `Edit page` without any errors.

However, the page **will not change**! It's like I'm not redirected at all. The edit page is not shown and I'm stuck on the page displaying the grid with all records I can copy.

**Can someone explain why the edit page is not shown?** Is there something really obvious I am not seeing?

Comment: Have you tried with return RedirectToAction("Index", model); (or)return View("ViewName");

Comment: `RedirectToAction()` will do exactly the same thing, while `View()` doesn't work at all, it doesn't even call the `Create` action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a silly error on my part.

The `Copy` action was called via `AJAX`, but I forgot to specify what to do with the `html` returned from the action.

I'm using `window.location = "/DemandeDeMontage/Copy/" + id` now instead.